# how in drupal forms can horizontal alignment of elements happen

Tags: forms, drupal

In drupal how do i align elements such as select boxes horizontallly with the title of the select box. ?

I dont want to hard code the format in template or the forms hook function.

I looked at modules like Form Builder and Arrange Fields but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS!
In Form API, you can use #attach property to attach online or CSS files that sets floating and display, etc CSS properties that you can use to set the layout of the form.

See #title_display property: you can set title display options such as 'after' and 'before'. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7

Answer (score 0):

You can try arrange form elements which allows you to define the alignment of label horizontally to the element its associated